# Oracle - Look up for the data in pivoted table

Tags: oracle, pivot

I have a table which has columns as follows: 
USERID, USERTYPE, DIVISION, SUBDIVISION

For each userid, there will be one or more usertypes (e.g. a user can be a developer or administrator or both). Depending on the usertype a user can be subscribed to the divisions and optionally its subdivisions.
USERID, USERTYPE and DIVISION are not null columns.

The output is required in the following format -

1. USERID, USERTYPE, DIVISION1, DIVISION2, DIVISION3 .. and so on 
   So, there should be a unique record for a combination of USERID-USERTYPE.
   For this I have used PIVOT operator which works fine. I have also created a temporary table (let's say Table1) to store this result of this query.
2. Now, if a user is subscribed to subdivisions, the values of subdivisions should be written under that division as comma separated values. If it is not subscribed to subdivisions, simple divisions will appear under its respective column. 
   I have written a query using LISTAGG function which gives me comma separated subdivisions for each USERID-USERTYPE combination. The result of this query is stored in Table2.

Now when I join the tables Table1 and Table2 on USERID and USERTYPE, I get multiple rows for a single USERID-USERTYPE combination, which is obvious but not what is needed.

Here is some sample data:

[image: Sample Data]

Please note the records for USERID = 3. 
What I am getting is in "Result of join query" and what I need is in "Final Result".

Also, I cannot use LISTAGG before the pivot query, because later on while building the pivot query it will be too tedious to list all the possible combinations of subdivisions.

I am sure I am missing some small point here, but cannot figure out what. 
Any suggestions or pointers will be of great help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no need to list all subdivisions in pivot query, just aggregate it within a groups of unique combinations of `USERID, USERTYPE, DIVISION` and use `nvl(AGGREGATED_VALUE,DIVISION)` to get a value for filling pivot table.

If `source_table` is a table with `USERID, USERTYPE, DIVISION, SUBDIVISION` columns which you mentioned first in your question, then this example must work for you:

```
select * from (
  select
    userid,
    usertype,
    division, 
    -- get prepared value for pivot
    nvl(
      listagg(subdivision, ',') within group (order by subdivision),
      division
    ) subdiv_list
  from
    source_table
  group by
    userid, usertype, division
)
pivot (
  max(subdiv_list) for division in ('Div1', 'Div2') 
)
```

[SQLFidlle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a4915/3)

*P.S. Just as a side story, generation of a list of columns dynamically may be useful. Check [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069992/sql-pivot-with-variable-columns).*

Comment: Hi ThinkJet, that worked like a charm! Thank you very much for the quick response.

Comment: @Leonine Is always pleasant to respond to well-formulated questions.